# Exercise about Birth and Death process

Tags: probability, markov-chains, means, variance, birth-death-process

I have some difficultes with an exercise that I must do. I try to post it there, maiby someone can help me to resolve it.

Let ${X(t)}_{t>0}$ on $\{0,1,2,3\}$ a birth end death process, with $\lambda(s)=(3-s)^2$ and $\mu(s)=s^2+s$.Furthermore we know that $P(X(0)=3)=1$. Determine:

1) $E[X(t)]$.

2) $Var[X(t)]$.

I tried to do the part one, but I'm stopped and I don't know how I can go one.

Let $M(t)=E[X(t)]$, I determine $M(t)$.

$M(t+h)=E[X(t+h)]=E[E[X(t+h)|X(t)]]$

$X(t+h)=\begin{cases}X(t)+1, \textrm{with probability } (3-X(t))^2h+o(h)\\X(t)-1,\textrm{with probability } (X(t)^2+X(t))h+o(h)\\X(t), \textrm{with probability } 1-[(3-X(t))^2+X(t)^2+X(t)]h+o(h)\end{cases}$

So $E[X(t+h)|X(t)]=(X(t)+1)P(X(t)+1)+(X(t)-1)P(X(t)-1)+X(t)P(X(t))=X(t)+[9-7X(t)]h+o(h)$

$M(t+h)=M(t)+[9-7M(t)]h+o(h)$

$\frac{M(t+h)-M(t)}{h}=9-7M(t)+\frac{o(h)}{h}$

I do this limit for $h\rightarrow0$ and i obtain this differential equation: $M'(t)=9-7M(t)$   (*)

Let $h(t)=9-7M(t)$,

so $h'(t)=-7M'(t)$

So I can rewrite the differential equation (*) in this way: $-\frac{h'(t)}{7}=h(t)$ or $\frac{h'(t)}{h(t)}=-7$

Integration yields: $\log[h(t)]=-7t+c$ or $h(t)=K\exp{-7t}$.

So $9-7M(t)=K\exp{-7t}$.

Now to detrmine K I think that I must use the condition that $P(X(0)=3)=1$, but I don't know how I use it. However I'm not sure that my reasoning is corect. I hope that someone can explain it to me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Did you read it before posting it?

Comment: Yes, why? Is it totaly wrong?

Comment: Did you notice those parts in red? That's because there are no `\with` or `\probability`commands in MathJax.

Comment: Yes I know, but I couldn't to write "with probability" in the brace and this is the only way that I found to write it.

Comment: You could write `\text{with probability}`.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. So I'll correct it.

Comment: I notice that you have alright do it.

Comment: Is $X(0)$ given?

Comment: Scuse me, I forget to write that P(X(0)=3)=1. I was sure to write it, sorry.